# Combining Sublists Sequentially Based on Similar Elements in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am attempting to combine sublists in a list of data given below:

```
Data={{{2, 6, 3, 5}, {4, 2, 5, 1}}, {{2, 6, 3, 5}, {6, 4, 7, 3}}, 
      {{8, 12 ,9 ,11}, {12 ,8 , 13, 7}},
      {{10, 13, 11, 14}, {14, 9, 1, 10}};
```

The goal is to combine sublists based on whether each pair has a similar term, like this:

```
FinalData={{{2,6,5,3},{4,2,5,1},{6,4,7,3}},
       {{8, 12 ,9 ,11}, {12 ,8 , 13, 7}}, 
        {{10, 13, 11, 14}, {14, 9, 1, 10}}};
```

I've attempted to solve this problem using multiple methods such as For loops, while loops, Gather, Union, and Select, but still am stuck. Would anyone be willing to help me out? First post here, and I am hoping to get some advice! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this perhaps a homework problem? Or part of one?

Comment: Have you looked at `GatherBy`

Answer (score 1):

this reproduces your example:

```
Union[Flatten[#, 1]] & /@ GatherBy[data, First]
```

Note this is only grouping where the *first* sublist is the same, and `Union` sorts the results. If you need it more general you should give a more general example.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Data //. {{h___,{p_,q_},m___,{p_,r_},t___}->{h,{p,q,r},m,t},
          {h___,{p_,q_},m___,{r_,q_},t___}->{h,{p,q,r},m,t}}
```

searches your data to find any list {p,q} and another list {p,r} and turns those into {p,q,r}. It also searches to find any list {p,q} and another list {r,q} and turns those into {p,q,r}. And it does that over and over until no further lists match. You should test that carefully to make certain that it is correct in all cases. You should look up //. which is also called ReplaceRepeated in the documentation to try to understand how that works. You should also look up "triple blank" which is three underscores in a row and is in the documentation as BlankNullSequence to try to understand how that works. And look up how putting a symbol in front of _ or ___ "names the pattern" to try to understand how that works. Understanding all this will give you new power to write programs to control Mathematica.